# Exact Query Match in Haystack not working

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have a product index with keywords as multivalued field

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    keywords = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True)

    def prepare_keywords(self, product):
        return [p.name for p in product.tags.all()]
```

I need to find Products having keywords exactly as `lightning` . I use this query -

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(keywords__exact=u'Lighting')
```

But this also gives me the Products having `lightning` as a part of the word. Like

```
print SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(keywords__exact=u'Lighting')[1].keywords

[u'LED lighting', u'Optic Lighting']
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: do you have a `prepare_keywords` method?

Comment: @tobltobs - yes, since its multiple values so I am passing a list of keywords for that product

Comment: update your question with search backend and haystack version.

Comment: @iamkhush Without knowing how your 'prepare_keywords' method looks we can only guess. I guess you make a split and feed every single word as value. If yes you would have to introduce a new index field containing the complete string. I could guess again how this should look ...

Comment: @tobltobs - yes, I am providing a list of keywords. I have added a prepare_keywords method.

Comment: Does there exists a tag with the name 'lightning'? If yes could it be that it is associated with the products which also have 'LED lighting' or 'Optic Lighting' as associated tags?

Comment: There might be some products which have all 3 - 'LED lighting', 'Optic Lighting' and 'Lightning' . But in the example in the question description there are just 2 tags. I dont want this product in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just look at `example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.conf`

```
<field name="keywords" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

i think the exact only worked on string fields not text fields. you must to edit this configuration and create keyword field like this:

```
<field name="keywords" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Awesome !! Any hacks to set this up on haystack?

Comment: @iamkhush this is solr configuration, haystack just using solr configred fields. you must fix solr configuration.